# Get user input length on typeahead:selected

Tags: typeahead.js

I'd like to track the effectiveness of typeahead (and my internal scoring algorithm) by tracking how many characters a user enters before selecting a result.

```
.on(typeahead:selected, function(datum, ob){
  // get the length of the input query
});
```

Here's the results I want:

```
INPUT QUERY      SELECTED         RESULT
-------------    --------------   ------
Michael          Michael Jordan   7
Stack            stackoverflow    5
Lar              Larry Bird       3
```

Comment: Post an answer to your own question instead of adding the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to modify the _select method in typeahead.js. Here's one way:

```
  _select: function select(datum) {
            //begin new code
            datum.special = this.input.getQuery();
            //end new code
            this.input.setQuery(datum.value);
            this.input.setInputValue(datum.value, true);
            this._setLanguageDirection();

            this.eventBus.trigger("selected", datum);
            this.dropdown.close();
            _.defer(_.bind(this.dropdown.empty, this.dropdown));
        },
```

Then you can call that in the selected event like this:

```
.on(typeahead:selected, function(datum, obj){
  console.log(obj.special.length);
});
```